# LINQ Group By to project into a non-anonymous type?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, group-by, anonymous-types

I have the following LINQ example:

```
var colorDistribution = 
    from product in ctx.Products
    group product by product.Color
    into productColors

    select
       new 
    {
       Color = productColors.Key,
       Count = productColors.Count()
    };
```

All this works and makes perfect sense.

What I'm trying to achieve is to group by into a strong type instead of anonymous type.

For example I have a ProductColour class and I would like to Group into a `List<ProductColour>`

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I'd completely misread your post. By the looks of it, you're not wanting to group *by* a different type - you're wanting to project each element of the group *into*  a different type. Here's what I'd do:

```
var colorDistributionSql = 
    from product in ctx.Products
    group product by product.Color
    into productColors

    select
       new 
    {
       Color = productColors.Key,
       Count = productColors.Count()
    };

var colorDistributionList = colorDistributionSql
      .AsEnumerable()
      .Select(x => new ProductColour(x.Color, x.Count))
      .ToList();
```

Comment: Right, lets give this a go...Thanks

Comment: @vikp: Please see the edit - I hadn't spotted this was SQL. I've now completely rewritten the answer, as your use of the phrase "group by" was confusing me. I see it's the *result* projection that you want to convert to a custom type, not the grouping projection.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit and the code snippet. 

In order to do this I won't have to override getHashCode() and equals() methods, right?

Comment: @vikp, no, because the GroupBy is performed by the DB, it doesn't actually execute any .NET code

Comment: Sort of weird why LINQ2SQL doesn't allow `select new ProductColour(...)` directly...

Comment: This line of code: 
.ToList(x => new ProductColour(x.Color, x.Count));

generates a following exception: No overload for method 'ToList' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? 
1. We group by criteria, E.g. Color.
2. We store the result of the query in a new anonymous type with two fields: Key and Count
3. We convert whatever is stored in the anonymous variable and store it in the list.

Is this considered as an elegant approach in LINQ? 

Thank you

Comment: @vikp: Hmm... I must have misremembered the overloads available. Will fix. But yes, that's the general approach.

Comment: Would be great if you could help out with the overload on a ToList(). In the mean time thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

LinqToSql does allow direct projection of the group into a type (after all, the group is just an `IGrouping<T, U>`, a type).  What LinqToSql can't do, is translate a constructor into SQL.

```
IQueryable<ProductColour> colorDistributionSql =  
    from product in ctx.Products 
    group product by product.Color 
    into productColors 
    select new ProductColour()
    { 
       Color = productColors.Key, 
       Count = productColors.Count() 
    };
```