# How to assign anonymous list to specific name or class type in LINQ Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I got LINQ query that is grouping Questions and their possible answers. I can get question as group.key but answers list is coming as anonymous list which I need to assign as 'AnswersList'

Refer to following screen shot where I also point that i need to assign 4 list to specific name

[image]

### Linq Script

```
var k1 = (from question in Context.Questions.Where(question => question.ConsultationId == ConsultationId && question.IsSubQuestion == false)
                  select new
                  {
                      question,
                      subQuestions = from subQuestion in Context.Questions
                                     join questionHierarchy in Context.QuestionHierarchy on subQuestion.Id equals questionHierarchy.ChildQuestionId
                                     where questionHierarchy.ParentQuestionId == question.Id
                                     join questionAnswerOptionsJoin in Context.QuestionPreDefineAnswerOptionJoin on subQuestion.Id equals questionAnswerOptionsJoin.QuestionId
                                     join preDefineAnswerOption in Context.PreDefineAnswerOptions on questionAnswerOptionsJoin.PreDefineAnswerOptionId equals preDefineAnswerOption.Id
                                     group preDefineAnswerOption by subQuestion into g
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         g,
                                         //answersList ={} ??????????????
                                     }
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the question here? And what is the point of that screen shot?

Comment: I want to assign collection to type, i.e. answerList = {collection} rather then just collection as shown in screen shot

Comment: Not sure how this is a sql server question.

Comment: in group I have record of two types, one is single record and other is collections, I need to assign it specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Group By to project into a non-anonymous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927618/linq-group-by-to-project-into-a-non-anonymous-type)

Comment: no, it is not, is count and in separate query, I want a collection in group result to a type

Comment: I need the answer to question, @toxic did you ever figure it out?